# excluding from an object angular ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

Hello guys i am trying to clear my ng-model when i fire my change function but my problem that i don't want to delete all i want to exclude one item in the object.

```
function change() {
            if (vm.location.type) {
                angular.forEach(vm.location, function (value, index) {
                    delete vm.location;

                });

            }

        }
```

so i don't want to delete the

```
vm.location.type
```

my

```
vm.location
```

has

```
              vm.location.boundaries;
              vm.location.region;
              vm.location.address;
              vm.location.name;
              vm.location.nonVisitingRadius;
              vm.location.visitingRadius;
```

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying but if you want to remove one key from object, then try like this: `vm.location.region;`

Comment: what i am trying to do is that i want to delete all the vm.location but i don't want to delete vm.location.type because i still need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i understand correctly what you're asking, but if you want to clear all the fields of your object preserving only type and preserving the reference of the object with plain javascirpt (no libraries), loop over the fields and check if the i field is equal to type.

```
for(var i in model.location){
if(i !== 'type')
  delete model[i];
}
```

with underscore.js you could define a default model like:

```
var defaultModel = {
 location: {
   region: '',
   address: '',
   name: '',
   nonVisitingRadius: '',
   visitingRadius: '',
   type: 'defaultvalue'
 }
}
```

and when ng-change is triggered inside the function

```
_.extend(model, defaultModel);
```

that will keep the default value for type and clear all the others.

Comment: thank's man i have done what you said and it is working .  for(var i in vm.location){
                if(i !== 'type')
                    delete vm.location[i];
            }

Answer (score 1):

See the code below,

```
var obj = { a:123, b:123, c:123 }
delete obj.a;
```

Hence obj will be like this {b:123, c:123}

> Note: Dont need any for loop to delete property from object

Updated Answer:

```
var obj= {
  a: 'aaa',
  b: 'bbb',
  c: 'ccc',
  d: 'ddd'
};

var removeObj = function(obj, props) {

    for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
            delete obj[props[i]];
        }
    }

};

removeObj (obj, ["a", "d"]);
```

Comment: i understand this but what if my obj has huge amount of items inside i will write 90 line to delete.

Comment: @HeshamElMasry are you using lodash in your project, if so then u can use _.emit(obj, ['a','b'])

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this with a temporary object :

```
let tempLocation = {};
tempLocation.type = $scope.location.type;
$scope.location = tempLocation;
```